# Convert arrays to son like string of objects in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have four arrays:

```
var attributes = ["a","b","c","d"];
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = [34,55,66];
var c = [22,23,53];
var d = [15,78,98];
```

How to merge them into one json like string in Nodejs?

```
[{"a":1,"b":34,"c":22,"d":14},
 {"a":2,"b":55,"c":23,"d":78},
 {"a":3,"b":66,"c":53,"d":98}]
```

Here is my code, but anyone have a better solution? I do need preserve the quote.

```js
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = [34,55,66];
var c = [22,23,53];
var d = [15,78,98];

var obj = "[";
for (var u = 0; u < a.length; u++) {
  var l = "\"a\":"+a[u]+",";
  var m = "\"b\":"+b[u]+",";
  var q = "\"b\":"+c[u]+",";
  var n = "\"d\":"+d[u]+"";
  if(u == (a.length-1))
    var k = "{" + l + m + q + n + "}";
  else
    var k = "{" + l + m + q + n + "},";
  console.log(k);
  obj = obj + k;
};
obj = obj + "]";
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: FYI - I removed the mention of JSON from your question because JSON is a text format for representing data when it needs to be sent over a socket or saved in a file. Your question is about the data in-memory, and has nothing to do with JSON.

Comment: You need to add the code you've attempted to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all the arrays are the same length, and hardcoding their names:

```
   var obj = []
    for (var u = 0; u < a.length; u++) {
        obj.push({
            'a': a[u],
            'b': b[u],
            'c': c[u],
            'd': d[u]
        });
    };
    obj = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

EDIT:  Converted the obj into a json string, the question had been mistakenly edited to ask for an array.

Comment: Thank you! The result of your code is [ { a: 1, b: 34, c: 22, d: 15 },{ a: 2, b: 55, c: 23, d: 78 },{ a: 3, b: 66, c: 53, d: 98 } ]. How to get "a" instead of a.

Comment: [{"a":1,"b":34,"c":22,"d":14},{"a":2,"b":55,"c":23,"d":78},{"a":3,"b":66,"c":53,"d":98}] not [ { a: 1, b: 34, c: 22, d: 15 },{ a: 2, b: 55, c: 23, d: 78 },{ a: 3, b: 66, c: 53, d: 98 } ]

Comment: Someone had edited your question asking for an array.  I edited my answer to turn it into a json string

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code will do the trick:

```
var arrays = [a, b, c, d]; // add all the arrays you want
var num = a.length; // or hardcode to the length you want

var result = [];
for(var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    var element = {};
    attributes.forEach(function(attr, index) {
        element[attr] = arrays[index][i];
    });
    result.push(element);
}
```

```js
var attributes = ["a","b","c","d"];
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = [34,55,66];
var c = [22,23,53];
var d = [15,78,98];

var arrays = [a, b, c, d];
var result = [];
var num = a.length;
for(var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    var element = {};
    attributes.forEach(function(attr, index) {
        element[attr] = arrays[index][i];
    });
    result.push(element);
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var attributes = ["a","b","c","d"];
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = [34,55,66];
var c = [22,23,53];
var d = [15,78,98];

var x = [];

for (var i=0;i<3;i++) {
  var obj = {};
  for (var j=0;j<attributes.length;j++){
    obj[attributes[j]]=eval(attributes[j]+"["+i+"]");
  }
  x.push(obj);
}
console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know there are multiple answers on this question already, but none seemed to handle the key arrays as variables who's names are introduced in the attributes array.  Since I assumed that was the point of the attribute array, my solution does just that using node's global scope.  It also does not assume that all the key arrays will be the same length as that is not specified (even though the example they are).

```
var attributes = ["a","b","c","d"];
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = [34,55,66];
var c = [22,23,53];
var d = [15,78,98];
var arr = [];
while(true){
    var obj = {};
    for(var i=0;i<attributes.length;i++){
    if(global[attributes[i]].length)obj[attributes[i]]=global[attributes[i]].shift();
  }
  if(Object.keys(obj).length)
    arr.push(obj);
  else
    break;
}
```

In the following fiddle, I had to emulate node's global scope by manually creating a global array, but you get the point:

**Fiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/trex005/vm1yeL5d/

**Important note** If the arrays are not actually in the global scope, but are in some other object, you can use that object in place of `global`